# In a github repository settings, what is difference between environments vs secrets

Tags: github

In a GitHub repository setting, there is an "Environments" tab and a "Secrets" tab. What is the difference between these 2 tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean the difference between Repository secrets and Environment secrets.

**Repository secrets** are simple secrets that you can create giving a name and value and then access it in your action.
**Environment secrets** give you more options on what job or branch can access a environment and its secrets. A workflow job cannot access environment secrets until the required reviewers approve.
Here an image of the possible configurations and the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment).

[image: Environment secrets configuration]